# Can I get the current rating of fuse wire from its gauge?

Tags: fuses, circuit-protection, reverse-engineering

I've got a very old piece of equipment with no manual/documentation/labelling that uses plan bare fuse wire in several locations in the wiring, that I'd like to replace with standard cartridge fuses.

Is possible to infer or calculate the rating of the fuse wire from a reasonably accurate measurement of the wire gauge? I have a micrometer so can get fairly accurate diameter, and the working voltage / approximate current range is known.

Given the nature of the equipment and vagaries of fusing it needn't be down to the last milliamp, but a reasonably close guesstimate of the number of amps would be nice to have.

I've done a fair bit of searching for fuse wire gauge Vs rated breaking current but as fuse wire is seldom used these days I'm not finding any good info.

Comment: Without knowing the material of the wire, unlikely. Test it to destruction or analyse the circuit to work out what the fuse protects and use information in data sheets to decide what fuse value is needed.

Comment: Whilst what Andy aka says is very true, *most* fuse wire is bare tinned copper (aka BTC) ( I can't think of a good reason for using anything else in 99% of cases) so you may get a start by reading this web page https://www.oznium.com/blog/how-to-determine-the-fuse-wire-size-for-your-project/ which is a typical example of the information out there if you do a search.

Comment: @PeterJennings that is generally incorrect. Fuse wire that you can buy is usually a proper alloy of lead and tin but, who knows what wire is used in the OP's device.

Comment: Do you still have an intact fuse? Without knowing the melting point it isn't possible to fully determine the characteristic, but just a cold resistance measurement of the fuse should be able to put you in the correct ballpark.

Comment: @Andyaka Quite likely, but not according to this site https://www.electricalsells.com/copper-fuse-wire-size-chart-in-swg/ which references the obsolete BS 6722:1986. I don't have access to this BS, so I can't confirm one way or the other. But then another site says *"Zinc, copper, silver, aluminum, or alloys of these metals or other metals are used to create the fuse element in order to give stable and predictable features."*.  In any case I did say the quoted chart was a **start**.

Comment: @PeterJennings BS 6722:1986 covers copper wire dimensions and, it mentions what copper wire electrically fuses at but, it doesn't mean BS 6722:1986 should be regarded as a specification for devices called fuses (a solder type alloy of lead and tin that may, in modern times use silver instead of lead).

Comment: It is not straightforward to design a piece of wire to act like a fuse.  Material, length of the wire, it's environment (ambient temperature), how it's attached at its ends, it's shape, all affect at what time*current product the wire will melt/open.  It takes a lot of modeling and testing (to verify the models) to get it close to what you need.

Comment: Looking at the wires connected to the fuse wire might tell you what you can safely change it out for. Check what gauge the wire is and compare that to local regulations on wire ampacity? Maybe derate some as you can't be certain the same gauge is used throughout the entire circuit, though. I'd get an electrician's opinion, personally.

Comment: @Heath - The problem with that approach is that the ampacity of a wire is only roughly related to it's fusing current, in the sense that the higher the ampacity the higher the fusing current.  If you want the wire to burn open at a given current level, so as to protect either the source or something downstream, ampacity is not what you want to use.

Comment: What is this piece of equipment?  You could experiment a bit.  Most fuse holders will hold fuses with a wide range of current ratings, from 0.5 A to over 20 A.  Put in a fuse holder.  If you know the equipment is working properly, then install a 20 A fuse and see if that works.  If YES, then move down to lower current fuses, repeating until the fuse blows during normal operation.  Then move back to a higher current fuse for use.

Comment: are you certain that the wire is a fuse?

Comment: @SteveSh it's a welder, so the circuit is dirt simple (it's fusing one leg of each capacitor in a bank) and the margin for error is likely pretty high as it's not a precision instrument.

Comment: @jsotola yes the limited info I have identifies it as a fuse and it's clearly a deliberately placed piece of fuse wire not matching any other hookup wire inside the machine (everything else is normal insulated wire).